# First-of-type returns multiple divs

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, frontend

`document.querySelectorAll('h4:first-of-type')` return multiple divs
when we have the DOM:

```
div
  h4
div
  h4
```

How to select only the first h4? ( Without specifying the div like div:first-of-type h4:first-of-type )

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('h4:first-of-type')[0]`?

Comment: `document.querySelector`?

Comment: Use `document.querySelector` instead of `document.querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 1):

`querySelector` instead an it will do the job
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

```js
const firstHeading4 = document.querySelector('h4:first-of-type')
console.log(firstHeading4)
```

```html
<div>
  <h4>Heading 1</h4>
</div>
<div>
  <h4>Heading 2</h4>
</div>
```